# menubar with susbsitems events

Tags: apache-flex, events, menubar

can any one help me regarding the events related to menubar sub items,
here is some code iam working with

```
        <menuitem label="Home"/>
        <menuitem label="AboutUs"/>
        <menuitem label="CoursesOffered">
            <menuitem label="UG">
              <menuitem label="CSE"/>
              <menuitem label="EEE"/>
              <menuitem label="ECE"/>
              <menuitem label="IT"/>
              <menuitem label="MECH"/>
              <menuitem label="CIVIL"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="PG">
              <menuitem label="CSE"/>
              <menuitem label="ECE"/>
              <menuitem label="MCA"/>
            </menuitem>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem label="Departments">
           <menuitem label="CSE" >
              <menuitem label="HOD" />
              <menuitem label="Staff" />
              <menuitem label="DeparmentGallary"/>
           </menuitem>
           <menuitem label="ECE">
              <menuitem label="HOD"/>
              <menuitem label="Staff" />
              <menuitem label="DeparmentGallary"/>
           </menuitem>
           <menuitem label="EEE">
             <menuitem label="HOD"/>
             <menuitem label="Staff" />
             <menuitem label="DeparmentGallary" />
           </menuitem>
           <menuitem label="IT">
             <menuitem label="HOD"/>
             <menuitem label="Staff"/>
             <menuitem label="DeparmentGallary"/>
           </menuitem>
           <menuitem label="MECH">
             <menuitem label="HOD"/>
             <menuitem label="Staff"/>
             <menuitem label="DeparmentGallary"/>
           </menuitem>
           <menuitem label="CIVIL">
             <menuitem label="HOD"/>
             <menuitem label="Staff"/>
             <menuitem label="DeparmentGallary"/>
           </menuitem>
           <menuitem label="SH"/>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem label="ExaminationSection"/>
        <menuitem label="TrainingAndPlacement"/>
        <menuitem label="Alumni"/>
        <menuitem label="ContactUs"/>
```

i want to handle events wen particular subitem is clicked

for example ,if submnu item hod of cse is clicked it should go to the particular mxml page ,and if hod of ece is clicked it shold goto other page 
how do i differentiate each page of particular deparment 
how do select that particulasr item of that particular submenu itm
if any one knows plz help meeeeeeee...................?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to add an `id` attribute to any menu item that is a leaf and store those id values in static constant fields in the corresponding class.

```
public static const None:Number = 0;
public static const CSE_HOD:Number = 12;
public static const CSE_STAFF:Number = 13;
//and so on
```

in the dataProvider

```
<menuitem label="CSE" id="0">
  <menuitem label="HOD" id="12"/>
  <menuitem label="Staff" id="13"/>
</menuitem>
<menuitem label="ECE" id="0">
```

and the `itemClick` event handler of the `MenuBar`

```
switch(Number(menuEvent.item.@id))
{
  case CSE_HOD:
    //deal with cse hod here
    break;
  case CSE_STAFF:
    //deal with cse staff here
    break;
    //and so on
  default:break; //switch defaults for non leaf menu items like CSE etc
}
```